# Azure Functions: Python: Unit Tests: Mock Application Settings with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, azure-functions

I am developing Unit Tests for a Python Azure Function. In this context I want to mock values from the Application Settings.

How can I mock the Application Settings using unittest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application settings are made available to the Function via environment variables and can be retrieved therefore by calling `os.environ["appsetting_name"]`.

To mock the application settings:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch.dict("os.environ", {"AppSettingKeyOne": "AppSettingValueOne", "AppSettingKeyTwo": "AppSettingValueTwo"})
def test_xxx(self):
    # Arrange
    x: str = os.environ["AppSettingKeyOne"]
    y: str = os.environ["AppSettingKeyTwo"]

    # Act

    # Assert
```